# how to overwrite the matrix correctly

Tags: c, matrix, valgrind

I have created a new matrix in which I write only odd numbers from the first matrix. Initially, the dimension 2 of the matrix was equal to 1. Do I need to realloc each row and if so, how. An error also occurs when malloc'ing 2 matrices

Function:

```
    int i,j;
    b->matr=(Line*)calloc(a->lines,sizeof(Line));
    for (i=0;i<a->lines;i++) {
        b->matr[i].arr=(int*)malloc((a->matr[i].n)*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0;i<a->lines;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<a->matr[i].n;j++) {
            if (a->matr[i].arr[j]%2 != 0) {
                b->matr[i].arr[j]=a->matr[i].arr[j];
                printf("%d",b->matr[i].arr[j]);
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Valgrind:

```
Matrix:
2
1 2
2 4 5
New Matrix:

1
5
==11435==
==11435== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11435==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 3 blocks
==11435==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 7 frees, 2,192 bytes allocated
==11435==
==11435== 24 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==11435==    at 0x48427B5: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11435==    by 0x10937E: newMatr (in /home/students/c/chmel.da/inf2/lab1/prog1)
==11435==    by 0x109255: main (in /home/students/c/chmel.da/inf2/lab1/prog1)
```

I tried to make a realloc of each line, but it didn't lead to anything.

Comment: Question: Why did you switch from using `calloc()` to `malloc()`? (`b->matr[i].arr[j]` will be uninitialised execpt for those assigned because of an odd value in the other array...)

Comment: Where's your code to free the memory? It isn't automatic in C,